# Representing News Post in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm currently working on a blog for a college news organization. Each post, though, will represent a full show, with multiple contributors and multiple titles.

For example, a post might have three news stories, each with its own title and some contributors for each:

1. "Story 1" by (id1) and (id2)
2. "Story 2" by (id3)
3. "Story 3" by (id4) and (id5)

So for each post, there would be an index (1, 2, 3...) for each individual story, a VARCHAR for the title, and id's that represent contributors, whose details are stored in another "contributors" table. The problem is that I don't know how many stories there will be, or how many contributors there will be per story. It could range from ~3 at the least to up to 6. In case our show expands in the future, I'd like to have the capability to scale up to even more than 6 posts, too.

I want to represent this structure concisely in a mySQL column, but I'm not sure how to do that. One solution would be to create another mySQL table to save the details for each individual story, but I'd prefer to avoid that hassle. The ideal solution would be if I could somehow create an "array" within a mySQL column, which could store (for each story) an index, a string, and multiple id's to show who the contributors are.

Is this possible, or will I have to create a new table to keep track of each story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a column - use a table. It can be a simple InnoDB table which doesn't really hurt performance at all. Define a combined primary key `(story_id, contributor_id)` and insert all contributions in that table.

What you name in your question is called a M:N table. Don't ever go there - it's a very bad thing to do and is, in fact, nearly impossible in relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself some future heartburn. Create the extra table. It looks like a table of [Posts] with a one-to-many relationship to [Stories] where [Stories] has a many-to-many relationship to [Contributors].

Answer (score 0):

You could store a comma-delimited string value of contributor ids or story ids in one column, but how, exactly would you relate them? What would seem to be your best bet in that case would be to make it an 'array' of 'arrays', where your main string consisted of pairs of strings strung together through commas.. I (so it's just my opinion, okay?) would avoid using unless totally necessary (can't think of one instance at this time)...

So create your relationships tables. Just to illustrate one approach to the idea:

```
-- a story may have multiple contributors
CREATE TABLE story_contributor_rel (
    story_id INT NOT NULL
    , contributor_id INT NOT NULL
)

-- a post may have multiple stories
CREATE TABLE post_story_rel (
    post_id INT NOT NULL
    , story_id INT NOT NULL
)
```

Or cheat it a bit, but I'd recommend against this also(!):

```
-- a less-normalized way
CREATE TABLE post_relationships (
    post_id INT NOT NULL
    , story_id INT NOT NULL
    , contributor_id INT NOT NULL
)
```

These are just the simplest approaches. Naturally, you'd want to have either additional indentity columns and/or proper indexing and primary key settings, but this is just the way I can illustrate the point I'm driving at better.

Imagine this too.. If you were to put all those relationships in logical columns, then without the application it would not be so easy for anyone to understand what's going on in your tables. If you don't put any logic in the table structures and if you would properly set relationships tracking (meaning relationship tables), then it would appear transparent. One look at these tables and one would not take long enough to understand..

That's just my opinion. :) Cheers!